# Slow rise time on MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, motor, pwm, rise-time

I'm doing this project, where i control the speed of a motor with a 0-3.3 V PWM signal from a microcontroller. In the test setup i use a function generator (Digilent Analog Discovery). I would like the PWM to run at 50 kHz, but for better measurements, I have lowered the frequency to 15 kHz, 50 % duty cycle.
My problem is, that there seems to be some sort of capacitance in my circuit, lowering the FET's rise time, when i test it.

The schematic:
[image]

- "Opdrifts_PSoC-Blæser_signal" is the microcontroller. It is here i supply the - PWM in my test setup.
- "R6" is where the motor will be. In the test i use a 10 kOhm resistor.
- "Scope" is where i measure relative to ground.

The measurement:

- Output signal
  [image]
  Rise time is measured to about 13 us.

Hope somebody here can help me out.

Comment: Is _Opdrifts_PSoC-Blæser_signal_ a push-pull output from the microcontroller? Or open drain?

Comment: Woops, forgot to write that i use a function generator as input in the test.
I use a Digilent Analog Discovery.

Comment: Whats your problem? What is your question? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure you put the "scope" node in the right place on the schematic? If that voltage changes at all, it's because your battery isn't doing a very good job supplying current to the "motor".

Comment: Solved it now. It was the "motor".
See answer below for details.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MOSFET drain has a lot of capacitance. The diode adds a bit, as does your 'scope probe. You should use a much lower resistance than 10K to simulate the motor.

Also, the 1N4007 is unsuitable for 50kHz, the reverse recovery time is of the order of 5-10usec (unspecified on datasheets). Use a Schottky diode such as 1N5819 for a low voltage motor (for higher voltages than about 30V-50V you can use an ultrafast silicon rectifier rather than a higher voltage Schottky) .

Comment: Oh god, I'm an idiot..
I just fetched a 10 kOhm pull up resistor from a logic level converter i had on the same breadboard.
I've tested it with a 25 Ohm now, and it works. Rise time is down to 35 ns.

Also good point about the diode. Haven't thought about that before.

Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. The diode thing won't bite you badly until you have an inductive load on there.